# React Typescript - dynamic types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

Is it possible to have dynamic type? I have a json like this

```json
{
  "fieldName": "Some text",
  "type": String,
  "inputType": "text"
},
{
  "fieldName": "Some bool",
  "type": Boolean,
  "inputType": "checkbox
}
```

And based on that json I would like to render field components like this one

```
const Field: React.FC<FieldInterface> = ({ name, type, handler }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<type>()

  const handleOnChane = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
    handler(name, e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{name}</label>
      <input
        type={type}
        id={name}
        onChange={handleOnChane}
        value={value}
      ></input>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Field
```

here are my interfaces

```
export interface FormInterface {
  fields: FieldPropInterface[]
  submitAction: Function
}

export interface FieldPropInterface {
  name: string
  inputType: string
  type: <Here I would like to have something but don't know what>
}

export interface FieldInterface {
  name: string
  type: string
  handler: Function
}
```

You see, I need that type to set type of useState hook variable.
Is it possible to do that?

Repo link:
https://github.com/johnathan-codes/react-form-from-json

Comment: have you already taken a look at the typescript typeof operator?

Comment: Consider reading typescript docs. It's kinda basics of the basics.

Comment: @A_A But that doesn't resolve a constructor like String to the type string-you're still relying on the types you supply. OP is trying to use runtime info for static typing.

Comment: I think what you actually want is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) which enforces a relationship between properties inputType and type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other responses will work, but they aren't making use of the full power of typescript.  What you want is to establish a relationship between the fields `inputType` and `type` such that fields with `{inputType: "checkbox"}` must always be `boolean`, `{inputType: "text"}` must always be `string`, and so on.

Here's how you would do that with [a Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) (you could also make use of a map or a conditional, but I won't get in to that).

```
type FieldPropInterface = {
    fieldName: string;
} & ({
    type: "string";
    inputType: "text";
} | {
    type: "boolean";
    inputType: "checkbox";
})
```

You need to read up a bit more on [the HTML input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) and its props because you want to treat a checkbox differently than a text input.  Checkboxes set their value through a `boolean` property called `checked` rather than `value` which is a string.  There are also loads of packages on npm that can make dealing with forms a lot easier.

If you want `useState` to be generic then your component `Field` should be generic.

You've also said that your `FieldInterface.handler` can be any type of `Function`, but you need to be specific about what that function is.

```
{ handler: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void; }
```

or maybe it can become a function of `value` rather than `event` with a different setup.

Are you sure that you know what you're doing when using the capitalized name `String`?  The capitalized name means that the value is the String constructor, whereas the lowercase means that the value is a `string`.  From [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html):

> Don't ever use the types Number, String, Boolean, Symbol, or Object
> These types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never
> used appropriately in JavaScript code.

If you are using this as a flag, just to say "this value is a string" or "this value is a boolean" you might consider using the literal string `"string"` and `"boolean"` rather than the object constructors, but I don't know where and how this is actually being used in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You helped me a lot.
I am trying to create own form generator, without using 3rd party libraries. I added a repo link to the question, maybe it will make my question clearer, I am not good at explaining something I don't fully understand.

Answer (score 2):

Use alternative types.

```
export interface FieldPropInterface {
  name: string;
  inputType: string;
  type: Boolean | String;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
export interface FieldInterface<T> {
  name: string
  type: T
  handler: Function
}

const Field: React.FC<FieldInterface<typeof type>> = ({ name, type, handler }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<type>()

  const handleOnChane = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
    handler(name, e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{name}</label>
      <input
        type={type}
        id={name}
        onChange={handleOnChane}
        value={value}
      ></input>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Field
```

Comment: This is not the way to go, you can't change the interface during the runtime.

Comment: Then you have only this way to use - `type: Boolean | String;`

Comment: Exactly. And this is what I have posted above.