# Type error pass dynamic generic type to forwardRef React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I have a react component with `forwardRef` in TypeScript

```
const MyComponent= <TData, D extends ElementType = TableRowTypeMap['defaultComponent'],P = {}> (props :PropsWithForwardRef<TData, D, P>) => {
   return ()
}

const FinalComponent: (<TData, D extends ElementType = TableRowTypeMap['defaultComponent'],P = {}>(props: PropsWithStandardRef<TData, D, P>) => ReactElement | null) =
    forwardRef<ReactTableRef<any>, ReactTableProps<any, any, any>>((props, ref) => <MyComponent {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />);

export default FinalComponent;
```

I used [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70248031/13346156) to do that, it works fine, but gets a type error (not stopping the application):

```
Type 'PropsWithForwardRef<any, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithForwardRef<TData, D, P>'.
```

I think the solution is passing `TData`, `D` and `P`, but when I do:

```
const FinalComponent: (<TData, D extends ElementType = TableRowTypeMap['defaultComponent'],P = {}>(props: PropsWithStandardRef<TData, D, P>) => ReactElement | null) =
    forwardRef<ReactTableRef<TData>, ReactTableProps<TData, D, P>>((props, ref) => <MyComponent {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />);
                             -----                   -----  -  -
```

I've got error that: Cannot find names `TData`, `D` and `P` !!

**Why? and What's the solution?**